# Assigning an ExtGState to a stroke in a PDF does not work

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation

I am trying to assign a ExtGState object to a stroke in a image stream in a pdf. The ExtGState should set the Blend Mode of the stroke. But no matter what, it does not work and the PDF Specification does not help.
I hope somebody here knows what to do.

Here is my ExtGState Object:

```
    5 0 obj
      << /Type /ExtGState
         /BM Multiply
      >>
    endobj
```

My Proc Set of the Page:

```
4 0 obj
  << /ProcSet [/PDF /Text]
     /ExtGState << /GS1 5 0 R
                >>
  >>
endobj
```

And finally the image stream

```
6 0 obj
  <<   >>
stream
 3 w
 0 0 0 RG
 1 J
 1 j
 178 2658 m
 310 2322 l 
 S


 10 w
0.13725490196078433 0.4196078431372549 0.5568627450980392 RG
 1 J
 1 j
 /GS1 gs
 [3 5] 6 d
 152 2423 m
 400 2600 l
 S
endstream

endobj
```

I am using /GS1 gs in order to assign the ExtGState Object to my second stroke. The first stroke is just for checking, if the blend mode works (which does not).

Here you can find my whole pdf: https://pastebin.com/nwGBb7vB

It is supposed to look like this:

[image]

Comment: Please share your whole example pdf. Also please show what you expected.

Comment: @KJ Actually you fixed the error in *"try `5 0 obj << /BM /Multiply /Type /ExtGState >> endobj`"* by adding the missing slash before `Multiply`. The order change is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your graphics state dictionary:

```
5 0 obj
  << /Type /ExtGState
     /BM Multiply
  >>
endobj
```

The `Multiply` needs to be a PDF name object. In particular it has to start with a slash:

```
5 0 obj
  << /Type /ExtGState
     /BM /Multiply
  >>
endobj
```

After this change you get:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Oh my gosh, thank you so much!! I spent hours trying to figure it out, thank you!